# How can I access the following data in PHP laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, eloquent

I want to access `user_projects` from the following data

```json
{
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Random",
    "description": "Null",
    "client_id": 3,
    "deadline": "2023-10-13 18:30:05",
    "status": "Proposal",
    "created_at": "2023-10-13T05:26:17.000000Z",
    "updated_at": "2023-10-13T05:26:17.000000Z",
    "user_projects": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Rosendo Pfannerstill III",
            "email": "admin@mallow-tech.com",
            "email_verified_at": null,
            "is_client": 0,
            "address": null,
            "country": null,
            "phone_number": null,
            "profile_image": null,
            "created_at": "2023-10-13T05:15:47.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2023-10-13T05:15:47.000000Z",
            "pivot": {
                "project_id": 1,
                "user_id": 1
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 22,
            "name": "MukeshPrakash",
            "email": "mukeshprakash87@gmail.com",
            "email_verified_at": null,
            "is_client": 0,
            "address": null,
            "country": null,
            "phone_number": null,
            "profile_image": null,
            "created_at": "2023-10-13T05:17:12.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2023-10-13T05:17:12.000000Z",
            "pivot": {
                "project_id": 1,
                "user_id": 22
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I am getting this output from the following controller function

```php
public function clientsAndUsers($id)
{
    $projects = Project::with('userProjects')->find($id);

    echo $projects;
}
```

This data is coming from a `belongsToMany` eloquent relationship. Instead of using `echo`, here I gotta send the data to a view but I have no idea how to access the `users_projects`.

I have tried this

```php
$projects->user_projects
```

And this

```php
$projects["user_projects"]
```

If I put this on a loop like this

```php
foreach($projects as $project) {
    echo $project;
}
```

It strangely returns `1` thrice. I have no idea why, and both are returning nothing so I can't put that in a loop as well.

So kindly help me access it and also explain a bit.

Comment: That looks like a JSON string - so you probably first need to decode it into a PHP array.  Try `$a = json_decode($projects, true);`, then you should be able to access `$a['user_projects']`

Comment: depending on what you will answer to @RobEyre, if it is not JSON data, but a model that you shared as JSON so it is understandable, either way you have to return a `view` or the data itself, not `echo` data, where are you using `clientsAndUsers` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You access it through your Eloquent relationship that you've eager loaded (using `with('userProjects')`):

```
$projects->userProjects
```

When Laravel converts models to json output, it automatically converts the relationship names to `snake_case`, which is why the `userProjects` relationship is output using the `user_projects` key. So, even though the json is showing `user_projects`, that key doesn't actually exist on the model object, which is why you can't access it like you've tried.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access the user_projects array in the data set, you can do

```
    public function clientsAndUsers()
{
     $data = Project::with('userProjects')->get();
     //$projects = $data->user_projects;

    return view('dashboard', ['data'=> $data]);     
}
```

Then in your blade view;

```
@foreach($data->user_project as $project)
  $project->id;
  $project->name;

@endforeach
```